# Reverting Oracle Database instance changes to a date before

Tags: oracle

I am a learner to SQL. I am using an enterprise software which uses Oracle as database.

The enterprise software is to be upgraded to a new version, both versions of software uses Oracle 11 g R 2. The upgrade received an error, but the user missed back up of oracle dump. Now the database is in corrupted state for Enterprise software to use.

I want to ask, is there a way to recover oracle instance to the state of previous day or a day before.

Comment: So you don't have a backup at all from prior to the start of the upgrade?

Comment: Yes David. Missed taking backup. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Will the database instance start, and open the database? What error messages do you see?

Comment: Sorry for late reply David. We moved to a backup taken few months ago.